# Maven Assembly plugin create a zip file

Tags: java, maven

I have a project structure like

```
src
----main
    -----resources
          -- 1.xml
          -- 2.xml
```

Now I need to create a zip file which contains only the xml files.

My pom.xml is like below.

```
 <groupId>tasks</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My zip.xml file is like below

```
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```

But when I do mvn clean install its creating a zip file with the below directories in it.

```
archive-tmp
classes
maven-archiver
resources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The xml files are coming in the classes folder.

How can I get only the xml files in my zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by modifying the zip.xml like below

```
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```